# how to add dynamic fields without library YII2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to add a textfield and image field with validation in my form. I want to achieve this customly means without using any built in library. I am using yii2 advanced.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Demonstration on how to implement dynamic tabular forms.

[Simple way to implement Dynamic Tabular Inputs](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/805/simple-way-to-implement-dynamic-tabular-inputs/)